# Multiple Modals and Clicking Away

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a modal that on click of a button, it opens.

I need to listen for click away events so I also have an event listener on the window. The problem is, as soon as the modal is open, the event bubbles and the modal is closed via the window event listener.

```
function open() {
    active.value = true;
    window.addEventListener('click', close);
}

function close() {
    active.value = false;
    window.removeEventListener('click', close);
}
```

I am aware that I could add `stop` here: `<button @click.stop="open">` to prevent the propagation to the window. Which indeed does work.

Unfortunatly, having multiple modals on the page, and having multiple buttons, if you try and "click away" from the current modal by clicking on a button that opens another modal, the event fails to propogate because of the`stop`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Don't listen for it via window event. The modal generally has a button clicked to toggle it, the eventListener should be listening to that. All we're doing is switching the display from none to something viewable. For closure, all modals should have a container that acts as the background covering 100% of the page. You can eventListen for it being clicked and it not being the Modal Content itself..

Comment: Try out `<button @click.self="open">`

Comment: @BGPHiJACK but i want to be able to click a modal and open another modal when its button is pressed. Your method would not allow that.

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim adding `self` does not, the modal no longer opens?